# PySpark - get value of array type from dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My data frame is like below. I need to extract values from input Array Type column. How can I achieve this in PySpark?

```
None
root
 |-- input: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: map (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: map (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |-- value: double (valueContainsNull = true)
 |-- A: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: map (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: map (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |-- value: double (valueContainsNull = true)
 |-- B: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: map (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: map (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |-- value: double (valueContainsNull = true)
 |-- C: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: map (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: map (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |-- value: double (valueContainsNull = true)
 |-- D: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: map (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: map (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |-- value: double (valueContainsNull = true)
 |-- E: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: map (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: map (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |-- value: double (valueContainsNull = true)
 |-- timestamp: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: map (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: map (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |-- value: double (valueContainsNull = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import chain
df.select('input').rdd.flatMap(lambda x: chain(*(x))).map(lambda x: x.values()).collect()
```